# Remove dots and signs around report text

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

I get dots and symbols around text in my report. I changed the font, but it didn't  correct the problem. Why are they appearing in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you have two or more fields overlapped on your report?

Comment: No, not that case

Comment: It looks like MS special strings for UI translators (sorry I couldn't find reference ATM), where most chars are replaced with diacritics version. From where your text comes? For example label - should it be Title or Țitlè? Does it come from database or is it written manually?

Comment: Does this happen only when you are exporting to PDF?

Comment: @Hexxx Yes, it happens only when I export to pdf.

Comment: @Arvo The labels are written manually.

Comment: Only PDF? Which version of Crystal Reports, which version of pdf export dll? In different CR versions there occur various PDF problems (we have spent long hours to cure them). Does your PDF look same, if viewed in some newer OS (W7, W10); does it look same when viewed in Foxit or other viewer?

Comment: @Sam Try my answer

Comment: I found that Unicode Fonts display text like shown above while as Non-Unicode Fonts are perfect. But I have to use Unicode font. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your field contains Unicode Characters and if I am to guess here the font you are using for that field does not support Unicode Encodings. Change the Font to `Arial Unicode MS` or any other font which supports Unicode characters.

Comment: I found that Unicode Fonts display like shown above while as Non-Unicode Fonts are perfect. But I have to use Unicode font. What should I do?

Comment: @Sam I am unable to follow you. correct me if i am wrong, You don't wish to use Unicode font for the text ?

Comment: I have to use Unicode because in my text are Chinese and Arabic characters. But it displays as shown in the picture.

Comment: Then what is the problem?use unicode fonts for the fields which contain chinese and arabic characters.